# hide menus that aren't currently selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu with headings. When a heading is clicked, the child menu items will open. I would like to show only the menu that has most recently been clicked. If `heading_practice` is clicked, and other menus are open, they will slideToggle close. How can I do this?

```
<div id="pageHeadings">
    <div id="heading_practice">                     
        <a href="#">
           <p>Practice Areas</p>
        </a>
        <div class="menu_practice">
           <p>test</p>
           <p>test2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="heading_about">                        
        <a href="#">
           <p>About</p>
        </a>
        <div class="menu_about">
           <p>test</p>
           <p>test2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

$("#pageHeadings div[class^=menu]").hide();

$("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function () { 
    if(!$(this).find('[class^=menu]').is(":visible")) {
        $(this).find('[class^=menu]').slideToggle("fast");      
    }

    //if element is clicked, hide all other menus
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGQ83/3/)

Comment: If I were you, I will assign all menu items with same class, then add a class "selected" to the class when clicked. Last, use jQuery selectors to select all menu items without the class "selected" and make them hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to perform a slideUp on all the other elements. This can be achieved like so:

```
$("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function () {
    var $menu = $(this).find('[class^=menu]');

    if ( ! $menu.is(":visible") ) {
        $menu.slideToggle("fast");      
    }

    $('[class^=menu]').not($menu).slideUp("fast");
});
```

Comment: This is the only answer that only toggles the clicked item if it is hidden, which seems to be more of what the OP wanted. +1

Comment: Just to throw this out there, if you are okay with adding a little CSS, you can really clean up the HTML and the jQuery as well. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/YGQ83/9/ ... And if you'd like to allow a second click to close the menus, you can clean it up even further: http://jsfiddle.net/YGQ83/10/

Comment: 100% agree with @AndyM's solution above, my code does work with the original problem but it would be a good idea to restructure it following best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line:

```
$('[class^=menu]').hide('fadeIn');
```

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //hide all dropdown menus
    $("#pageHeadings div[class^=menu]").hide();

    $("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function () {
        // $(this).find('[class^=menu]').hide();
        if (!$(this).find('[class^=menu]').is(":visible")) {
            $('[class^=menu]').hide('fadeIn');
            $(this).find('[class^=menu]').slideToggle("fast");

        }
    });

});
```

That will hide all others before toggling the current one.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YGQ83/7/)

Answer (score 1):

One new line in your click function is all you need (and you can lose the `if` check):

```
$("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function () {
    $("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").not($(this)).find('[class^=menu]').slideUp();
    $(this).find('[class^=menu]').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9BrZf/)**